# Разумно ли использовать aws после блокировок?

Tags: hosting, amazon-web-services, amazon

Я выбираю облачного провайдера и смотрю в сторону aws, несмотря на то что активная блокировка телеграм уже прекратилась, по-прежнему остается заблокированными >1.65 млн ip адресов, а так как больше всего от этого пострадал амазон, то встает вопрос о возможности его использования в России (aws регион - Франкфурт), спасибо.

Comment: Предлагаю генерализовать вопрос до "разумно ли использовать Интернет после блокировок?"